# Overall connection without IP apache

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, apache-2.4, console

I'm trying to locate problem at my site and really slow loading and response Command

```
netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

is give me overall connections per IP address

But check the result... what is last one 3270 without IP?

Sreen
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNseT.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That figure is a total. It arises from your uniq -c command.

Your command produces a large number of blank lines, due to the way you are using cut, and uniq is counting the number of blank lines it finds.

It isn't the number of connections from a particular (unknown) ip address.